# Opening Image Through Python Shell

Tags: python, python-3.6

I need to open an image through python shell. The code i have used is :

os.startfile("C:\Users\Devanand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Code3\girl.png")

But it gives Error.

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

How do i resolve this error and make it work?

[image from the python shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wt5r.png)

.

.

.

.

.

Second problem is:
I need to open an image from python shell for selecting ROI/Bounding boxes for which i have written he code.

the python script what i used is:

try1 -i girl.png

Where try1 is name of the file.

This script shows error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax for "girl"

[python shell showing invalid syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2tXK.png)

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Escape the backslashes or make them raw strings using `r`, like `os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Devanand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Code3\girl.png")`

Comment: is there any space or hyphen after 'r' ?

Comment: No. `r'C:/path/to/file'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for the second question:**

you need a real shell, like cmd and powershell on windows or bash on linux to execute your program. The python shell is used to run python commands.

So just open cmd, cd to your folder where try1.py is saved and type the following:

```
try1.py -i girl.png
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `path`, there is a `'\U'`, in the `C:\Users...`. `\U` should be followed by unicode codepoints.

`\x` for 2 digits
`\u` for 4 and
`\U` for 8

For example:

```
>>> '\U0001F554'
''
>>> '\u2713'
'✓'
```

You need the escape the `\` or make it a `raw` string using the `r` like,

```
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Devanand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Code3\girl.png")
```

**And for the second question:**

You are inside the interpreter. Did you mean to use `python try.py -i girl.png` from a shell/cmd. It hard to exactly tell what you are doing without seeing the code. What is `-i` ? Could you show us the code ?

Comment: Oh yes. Got it. Thank You so much.

Comment: i have one more question regarding this problem. i would like to ask that.

Comment: You are inside the interpreter. Did you mean to use ` $ python try`.py -i girl.png`. It hard to exactly tell what you are doing without seeing the code. What is `-i` ?

Comment: this is to construct parser and to parse the argument it :   ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path of image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
--image is the path to the image that is to be cropped

Comment: Okay. Then you need something like `python try1.py -i girl.png` from the command prompt, since you seem to be on windows

Comment: Oh......thank u once again. total life saver u are. thank you so much.

Comment: i have another question as well. regarding same problem. but related to video input

Comment: So basically I wanted to select region of interest from the input video. once taking video as input and after pressing a key to select ROI i get error as follows:

 RESTART: C:/Users/Devanand/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Code3/video_roi.py 
usage: video_roi.py [-h] -i CAP
video_roi.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--cap

Internal code is same as my second problem mentioned in my question asked which is of argument passing.
So how i resolve this problem?

Comment: Finally what i want to do is, take video as input, press a key for selecting ROI (which will stop the video after pressing the key), and then press the same key , then video should start again with the ROI present in it.